# При запросе браузером css файла статус код по непонятным причинам становится в pending

Tags: node.js

При запросу браузером (Chromium) css файла статус код по непонятным причинам становится в pending, браузер запрашивает его через: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">`. Это случается не постоянно, через раз, два где-то. После секундн 20-30 статус становится на (canceled).Однако, если напрямую "заходить" на css файл проблем не возникает. И в firfox вообще нет проблем, работает всё гладко. Файл отдаётся через такой код:

```
    res.writeHead (200,{
Content-Type: 'text.css'
});
    res.end(file);
```

Comment: В Firefox также не робит.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же не указали путь к стилю. В `href` путь к стилю укажите:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
```

Comment: не не, это пример, путь указан. Этим линком хотел показать, что запрос инициирует браузер

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в на правильном исспользовании объекта res.